# Why is the default LN channel limit set to 16777215 sats?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-rfc

I assume this default limit of 2^24 is set by some purpose in [BOLT #2](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md). But what's the meaning of that? Or is there any test/experiment to support this number?

Answer (score 6):

The goal was to limit the amount any individual adopter would lose due to bugs in the software. As explained by LN developer Rusty Russell in [#bitcoin-lightning FAQ: Why the 0.042 bitcoin limit?](https://rusty-lightning.medium.com/bitcoin-lightning-faq-why-the-0-042-bitcoin-limit-2eb48b703f3):

> I **guarantee** that early releases of lightning clients will have bugs
> and **people will lose money** because of them. […] I sleep better at
> night knowing that, if you lose money because of my bug, I can buy you
> a beer/coffee in exchange for your story and we’re about even. (emphasis in original)

This answer was sourced entirely from [Bitcoin Optech: Large Channels](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/large-channels/) where you can find even more resources on this topic.